# computed свойство вызывается раньше, чем отработает action и mutation

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Проблема вот какая. Есть примерно такое:

```
async created() {
  await this.$store.dispatch('UserInfo/loadUserInfo'); // загрузка инфы о юзере
},
computed: {
  userInfo() { // это вызывается раньше, чем то, что в хуке created(), как следствие, ошибки в консоль и undefined повсюду.
    return this.$store.state.UserInfo.userInfo;
  },
}
```

Я не могу понять, как разрешить этот косяк. Как заставить вычисляемое свойство отработать после того, что в `created()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как заставить вычисляемое свойство отработать после того, что в created()

Никак.
Вам нужно просто дефолтное значение в сторе, чтобы не было ошибки чтения свойства, пока не будут загружены данные. Либо в самом геттере и проверяйте:

```
return this.$store.state.UserInfo ? this.$store.state.UserInfo.userInfo : {/*дефолтные данные*/};
```

Comment: Спасибо, дядь! Был уверен, что есть варик нормально написать. А документация молчит по этому поводу.